# Jenkins File Environment variables

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below Jenkins pipeline for my project where I am setting a variable COLLECTOR_TOKEN which will be set via shell script.

I want to handle a negative scenario where suppose if the shell script fails I send and exit code 1, which in return fails the entire pipeline (this is what we are expecting) but the issue is in the logs we cant see the proper error message, so it will hard to debug.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'maven' }
    options { timeout(time: 300, unit: 'MINUTES') }
    environment {        
        def COLLECTOR_TOKEN = sh(script: "chmod -R 777 *; hello.sh moshin", returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
}
```

Exception : We can just see the below exception.

I want to handle the below exception and throw proper message. how can we achieve it?

```
Error when executing always post condition:
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.StepDescriptor.checkContextAvailability(StepDescriptor.java:266)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:263)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at stepFinalise.call(stepFinalise.groovy:3)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:56)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(ModelInterpreter.groovy:137)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(ModelInterpreter.groovy:756)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:395)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:393)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(ModelInterpreter.groovy:755)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2030)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2015)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2056)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(ModelInterpreter.groovy:745)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(ModelInterpreter.groovy)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executePostBuild(ModelInterpreter.groovy:723)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor516.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:107)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor516.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:89)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor516.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Is this the entire pipeline? it seems there is some issue  while executing your post build section. syntax issues maybe.

Comment: Yes there is an issue with the below line and that is expected. I need to handle this exception.

```
def COLLECTOR_TOKEN = sh(script: "chmod -R 777 *; hello.sh moshin", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Comment: You get the exception because `def` is not allowed in `environment` block. See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment. To catch any _expected_ exception, write a function which in turn calls the shell step. In the function you can use `try` and `catch`.

Comment: Your issue is due to calling `sh` inside `environment`. `sh` can only be called inside `node`. You can run a small `node(...) { sh (...) }` before your pipeline to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution :
As I was using returnStdout with shell script and the result for that shell script was not always the correct output sometime I use to get some exception which was not getting handled in the Jenkins files. So I had to handle the exception of the shell script by sending a error message instead of exit 1. And then in pipeline stage step we had to validate whether we got the token or we got exception (based on the message we sent from shell script).

If exception then stop the build.

Below code is just for your reference.

```
moshin.sh file: 

#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == "moshin" ]]; then
  echo "moshin"
else
  echo "not_moshin"
fi
```

```
Jenkins Pipeline: 
pipeline {
    agent { label 'maven' }
    environment {
        COLLECTOR_TOKEN = sh(script: "chmod -R 777 *; moshin.sh moshin" , returnStdout: true).trim()
        COLLECTOR_TOKEN_1 = sh(script: "chmod -R 777 *; moshin.sh not_moshin" , returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
    stages {
        stage('PASS') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (env.COLLECTOR_TOKEN == "moshin") {
                        println "hello moshin"
                    } else {
                        println "Unable to fetch COLLECTOR_TOKEN"
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
                        sh "exit 1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('FAIL') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (env.COLLECTOR_TOKEN_1 == "moshin") {
                        println "hello moshin"
                    } else {
                        println "Unable to fetch COLLECTOR_TOKEN"
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
                        sh "exit 1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
Build output: 

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ chmod -R 777 Jenkinsfile moshin.sh
+ moshin.sh not_moshin
[Pipeline] sh
+ chmod -R 777 Jenkinsfile moshin.sh
+ moshin.sh moshin
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (PASS)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
hello moshin 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (FAIL)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Unable to fetch COLLECTOR_TOKEN
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: FAILURE
```